# Equivalence of Polignac to finite Goldbach?

Tags: goldbach-type-problems

Is Polignac's conjecture equivalent to a finite form of Goldbach? There is some discussion [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/191770/is-n-p-q-equivalent-to-goldbachs-conjecture) as to the difference between Polignac & general Goldbach, but the similarity seems particularly striking when Polignac is represented by scatterplots such as

[image]

plotted with

```
piQpairs[r_, ap_] := Select[With[{rr = Floor[PrimePi@r + Sqrt@r]}, {#, # + ap} & /@ 
Select[Prime@Range@Prime@(rr), PrimeQ[# + ap] == True &]], #[[2]] < r &]
With[{r = 1000}, 
Show[Reverse@(Length@# & /@ (piQpairs[r, #] & /@ Range[2, r, 2])) // ListPlot, 
Show[ListLinePlot[{{0, 0}, {r/2, Length@piQpairs[r, #]}}, PlotStyle -> Red] & /@  
(Select[Times @@ Prime@Range@# & /@ Range@Ceiling@Log[r/2], # < r/2 &])]]]
```

(for `r=2*10^4`), which shows the number of pairs (in reverse order) of $n-2n$ for $1\leq n\leq N/2$ for $\{p,p+2n\}.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what you mean by "a finite form of Goldbach". At any rate, I don't think it is known that Polignac's conjecture implies Goldbach conjecture or a slightly weaker form of it. It is known, however, that if a generalized Elliott-Halberstam conjecture holds and the twin prime conjecture is *false*, then every sufficiently large even number lies
within 2 of the sum of two primes. See Theorem 5 in the [Polymath8b paper](http://www.resmathsci.com/content/1/1/12). Perhaps this result can be generalized to: if a generalized Elliott-Halberstam conjecture holds and Polignac's conjecture is *false*, then every sufficiently large even number lies
within bounded distance of the sum of two primes.

Note also that the Polignac conjecture and the Goldbach conjecture are special cases of the conjectures of Dickson and Hardy-Littlewood, so it is not surprising if they have similar features.

Comment: I'm not sure which Dickson and/or Hardy-Littlewood conjectures have Goldbach as a special case. I don't even see how Schinel's Hypothesis H implies Goldbach.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: I think I got confused by history a bit. At any rate, Hardy and Littlewood did conjecture an asymptotic formula for Goldbach's conjecture, and they gave a heuristic for it in their paper "Some problems of ‘Partitio numerorum’; III: On the expression of a number as a sum of primes". In the same paper, they also gave an asymptotic formula for Polignac's conjecture, with a similar heuristic and a similar shape. See Conjecture A (on page 32) and Conjecture B (on page 42) in the paper (available online as http://fuchs-braun.com/media/8cdd73c813c342f8ffff80d1fffffff0.pdf).

Comment: @GHfromMO thanks for the response - the Polymath link is great - certainly, I think Zhang's result will continue to have far reaching implications as bounds are continually sharpened. As I understand from Tao's blog though, the parity problem stands in the way of reducing the bound to $2.$ It is interesting then, when you mention results that are a consequence of twin primes *not* holding.